# INDEX NAME on PRIMARY KEY

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, primary-key

I would like create a table and add to it a Primary Key.

As for my understanding MS SQL add a clustered Index on the Primary Key and will name it with a default name.

I would like to know if is possible create a table and ASSIGN a custom name for the index created by default or how can i change the default name after the table as been created.

Thanks!

Comment: for the index? or for the column (key)?

Comment: In SQL server you don't _have_ to put a clustered index on a primary key. Yes, it's the default, but `primary key nonclustered` works as well. Unless you don't add another clustered index, table will be heap.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure - you can define the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint in your `CREATE TABLE` statement.

This will generate the default `PRIMARY KEY`

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table
  (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    .......)
```

but you can totally define the name of the constraint, too:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2
  (ID INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_Table2 PRIMARY KEY,
    ......)
```

Comment: ok great, but how can i choose the name of index instead of using the default one?

Comment: @GlbboK: see my second example - you can choose the name for the CONSTRAINT which is also the name for the index: `CONSTRAINT PK_Table2 PRIMARY KEY` - you get to choose whether it's called `PK_Table2` or whatever else you might want to call it....

Answer (score -3):

When you create a Clustered Primary Key, you do´nt create a index, but a Table organized as index.

Clustered Primary key is default option when you create a table with primary key on SqlServer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933131(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: Oh yes, you **DO** create an index! It's the clustered index - and yes, the table is arranged by that index - but it's still an index no less.

Comment: I use oracle. On oracle IOT Tables (Organization Index) are similar to SqlServer Clustered Tables. The segment for the index on a IOT Table is named as TableName (is same segment).